# What's wrong with this mini HashMap?

Tags: c, hashmap, clang

I am trying to implement a simple HashMap with only `new` `get` and `insert` functionalities.
There's a very simple test function which is currently not passing.

The output:

```
test: Assertion `el == -10' failed.
```

When debugging the test, I get:

```
key: hhh value: 300
key: aba value: 300
```

When it shuold be:

```
key: hhh value: 10
key: aba value: -10
```

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include<assert.h>

#define N (1000)
#define MULTIPLIER (37)

typedef struct Node {
    char* key;
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct HashMap {
    Node* data[N];
} HashMap;

void test();

unsigned long hash(const char* key);
HashMap* new_hash_map();
void insert_element(char* key, int value, HashMap* hm);
int get_element(char* key, HashMap* hm, int* el);

unsigned long hash (const char* s)
{
    unsigned long h;
    unsigned const char* us;

    us = (unsigned const char*) s;

    h = 0;
    while (*us != '\0'){
    h = h * MULTIPLIER + *us;
    us++;
    }
    return h % N;
}

HashMap* new_hash_map()
{
    HashMap* hm = malloc(sizeof(HashMap));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    hm->data[i] = NULL;
    }
    return hm;
}
void insert_element(char* key, int value, HashMap* hm)
{
    unsigned long hk = hash(key);
    Node* ll = hm->data[hk];
    if (ll == NULL) {
    ll = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    ll->key = key;
    ll->value = value;
    ll->next = NULL;
    return;
    }
    for (; ll != NULL; ll = ll->next){
    if (strcmp(ll->key, key) == 0){
        // already exists
        ll->value = value;
        return;
    }
    }
    // new element, same hash key
    ll->key = key;
    ll->value = value;
    ll->next = NULL;
}

int get_element(char* key, HashMap* hm, int* el)
{
    unsigned long hk = hash(key);
    Node* ll = hm->data[hk];
    if (ll == NULL) {
    return -1;
    }
    for (; ll != NULL; ll = ll->next){
    if (strcmp(ll->key, key) == 0){
        // already exists
        *el = ll->value;
        return 1;
    }
    }
    return -1;
}

void test()
{
    HashMap* hm = new_hash_map();
    int el;
    insert_element("aba", 10, hm);
    insert_element("hhhh", -10, hm);
    get_element("hhhh", hm, &el);
    assert(el == -10);
    get_element("aba", hm, &el);
    assert(el == 10);
}

int main () {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `if (ll == NULL) {
    return -1;
    }` not needed in `get_element()`.

Comment: Tip concerning `#define N (1000)`.  Use `#define N 997u`.  A good hash function is good regardless of `N`, yet a weaker hash function typically benefits with a mod by a prime number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the primary problem is that you never inserted anything, You got prepared , allocated and then assigned to appropriate members and then you simply returned from the function.

Assign the allocated memory to `hashmap`s `data`.(`hm->data[hk] = ll`). Also check the return value of `malloc`.

Also the second loop is quite misleading in that - you end up with `NULL` in `ll` and then you dereference it. You should allocate and do the same thing as you did before.

```
   for (; ll != NULL; ll = ll->next){
    if (strcmp(ll->key, key) == 0){
        // already exists
        ll->value = value;
        return;
    }
    }
    // if the ll is NULL (in case it doesn't match) 
    // the you wil dereference NULL leading to UB.
    // new element, same hash key
    ll->key = key;
    ll->value = value;
    ll->next = NULL;
```

Dereferencing the `NULL` value is Undefined behavior. Here the probable solution would be to allocate memory for this new node and then assign it to a slot in hashmap.

From [standard 6.5.3.2p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4)

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an
>   object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand
>   has type ''pointer to type'', the result has type ''type''. **If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
>   unary * operator is undefined**.

On footnote

> Among the **invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*`
>   operator are a null pointer**, an address inappropriately aligned for
>   the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the
>   end of its lifetime.

Comment: ... and fix the loop that ends at a null dereference on collision-search exhaustion.

Comment: @WhozCraig I a not sure I follow. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @Blas Suppose you fix the code that stores the entry. Now suppose you have a collision on a new insertion, and determine the keys do NOT match, you'll walk the list to the end, where `ll` becomes NULL, then proceed to do `ll->key = ...` etc That's *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @WhozCraig If there's a collision, I am missing further allocation, right? And I don't understand how it is that I am not storing the entry. Isn't `ll->value = value;` doing it?

Comment: @Blas When code attempts `ll->value = value;`, `ll` is a _null pointer_.